# How to identify a crashing child with CreateProcess

Tags: c, winapi

I have a program where I call `CreateProcess`, then wait for it to finish with `WaitForSingleObject`, and finally I grab its exit status with `GetExitCode`. (However, the status variable contains 0 for crashed processes.) <- My apologies, this was incorrect. I was printing with the wrong size of variable.

How do I detect when the child crashed?

Comment: You are abusing the term "segfault". It's not the only reason for a crash and furthermore windows doesn't have it.

Comment: My question is unnecessary ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a control over child process make it return distinct error code on success, whereas if 0 then it means program crashed.

Comment: Please see the latest edit, I made a mistake. The crashing process returns a negative value.

Comment: @Tordek Then please delete/close your question.